# Why are the possible values of $x$ when $x^2+1=0$ both $x = i$ and $x = -i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

According to this calculator:

https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator/x%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%3D0?fbclid=IwAR3QaB2KCg2CCuYdvry1FhLD17WcyUN00QzO5B3U4SPbS_WHaihmL5bye44

The possible values for $x$ when $x^2+1=0$ are $i$ and $-i$.

If $$x^2+1=0$$, then why are the possible answers both $i$ and $-i$?

Original equation:
$$x^2+1=0$$

subtract $1$ from both side:
$$x^2=-1$$

Take the square root of both sides:
$$\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{-1}$$

Simplify only the left side:
$$x=\sqrt{-1}$$

Since $i$ is equal to $\sqrt{-1}$, I replace $\sqrt{-1}$ with $i$:
$$x=i$$

Where does the $x=-i$ come from?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $x^2=z$ then $(-x)^2=z$ too

Comment: Is $-2$ not a square root of $4$? There's a reason why square root isn't a function without restrictions.

Comment: To elaborate on @DonThousand's comment: $\sqrt 4 = 2$, but the solutions of $x^2=4$ are $\pm\sqrt4 = \pm2$. Same in your situation.

Comment: @DonThousand yes, but I wouldn't write it as +/- sqrt(4).

Comment: @LVBen How would you write it?

Comment: I would just write sqrt(4), which can be +2 or -2.

Comment: I found on wikipedia, that the definition of i is ambiguous, thus the problem.

Comment: No, LVBen. This is WRONG. With real numbers when $a\ge 0$, $\sqrt a$ denotes the *positive* (or nonnegative) square root, not "either one." When you work with complex numbers, there is no unambiguous choice, so you write down $\pm$ for both. That is, both $i$ and $-i$ are square roots of $-1$.

Comment: OK, so when I take the sqrt of both sides like above, I should've written as ±√x^2=±√-1 ?

Comment: $\sqrt {x^2} = |x|.$  This is the very definition of the absolute value function (or, it is a perfectly valid definition).  The square root maps only to the positive root.  So, $\sqrt 4 = 2.$ While $x^2 = 4$ has two solutions, $x = 2$ and $x = -2.$

Comment: @DougM: That's only valid for *real* numbers $x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Indeed, it is.  My comment was in response to other comments regarding the real case.  But as the original post deals with complex numbers, I will remove my comment.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2-a^2 = (x+a)(x-a)$, so the solutions are $x=a$ *and* $x=-a$. In other words, the solutions are $x=\pm\sqrt{a^2}$.

Comment: this is for $a\in \Bbb R$?

Comment: No, this is totally general. Only when $a^2$ is nonnegative and real do we have a unique choice for the square root.

Comment: So you're saying $\sqrt{-1}$ means *a* square root of $-1$.  (Wouldn't some say $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined unless $x$ is a non-negative real number?)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No, it is a multi-function, not a (single-valued) function.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions in order:

> ...why are the possible answers both $i$ and $-i$?

Because if you replace $x$ with either of them in the equation $x^2+1=0,$ you get a true statement.

> Where does the $-i$ come from?

Well, I wouldn't solve that equation like you did. For example, at a point you wrote $\sqrt{ x^2}=\sqrt {-1}.$ But what does this mean, since the *operation* $\sqrt{}$ is only defined for nonnegative arguments? Rather, I would note that $$x^2+1=x^2-(-1)=x^2-i^2=(x-i)(x+i)=0,$$ etc. However, we don't need all that. The equation $x^2+1=0$ is pretty basic, and we use it to define what we mean by $i,$ by saying that it has the property $i^2=-1.$ Of course it's not the only number with this property.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\sqrt{k^2}=\pm k$.

Now simplifying your observation-

$$ x^2=-1 => x=\sqrt{-1} $$

We know $\sqrt{-1}=\iota$

$$ x=\pm \iota $$